# Null typesafety in Reactor code in Kotlin and IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin, nullable, project-reactor

I have the following code in my Kotlin class:

```
Mono.just("banana").subscribe({
    println(it)
})
```

IntelliJ IDEA tells me that the variable "it" in this case has type "String!" (see screenshot).

[image: IntelliJ IDEA screenshot]

I'm not sure if this is an issue with Kotlin, IntelliJ IDEA or Reactor, but according to the [Project Reactor documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#kotlin-null-safety), it should have null annotations, and the Mono class does not allow null values to be passed.

I'm using Kotlin version 1.3.31 and have the following in my pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <args>
                    <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                </args>
                <compilerPlugins>
                    <plugin>spring</plugin>
                </compilerPlugins>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.31</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

So my question is, why is the variable "it" of type "String!" rather than "String"?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that Kotlin treats all types from a non-null-safe platform (like Java) as a platform type so it doesn't matter what the docs say in this case. If something you try to use (`Mono` in this case) is not written in Kotlin it will be a platform type.

You can [annotate your Java methods](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations) to alleviate this problem so in your case my guess is that `Mono` doesn't have any of the annotations from this list:

- JetBrains (`@Nullable` and `@NotNull` from the `org.jetbrains.annotations` package)
- Android (`com.android.annotations` and `android.support.annotations`)
- JSR-305 (`javax.annotation`)
- FindBugs (`edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations`)
- Eclipse (`org.eclipse.jdt.annotation`)
- Lombok (`lombok.NonNull`).

Comment: The classes in reactor apply the JSR-305 annotations, as you can see in the documentation link in the question. You can also see it here: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/package-info.java. This is why I am confused. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Which version of IDEA are you using? Which version of Kotlin & Kotlin plugin? My experience is that if you don't have the same version of Kotlin & Kotlin plugin in IDEA or if you have an old IDEA weird things like this might happen.

Comment: IDEA 2019.1.3 Ultimate. Kotlin version 1.3.31. Kotlin Maven plugin has no version specified, so I guess the latest, which would also be 1.3.31.

Comment: Oh and the IntelliJ Kotlin plugin is also 1.3.31.

Comment: Then this is weird. It is supposed to work. One option is to disable the warning (I don't recommend it). Or you can write to JetBrains support. This is a bug on their part I think. But first I'd check the actual source code of `Mono`, maybe this is a bug on their part, who knows.

Answer (score 0):

Type names or class names ending with single exclamation mark are called **Platform Types** in Kotlin. The subscribe in this case is returning a Java `String` without annotations, Kotlin doesn't know whether that value can or cannot be null.

You're correct that `null` cannot be passed into `Mono.just` but the result of the subscribe is not similarly annotated.

In that way, this is an issue with Reactor, but given the complex generics which are likely involved it could be infeasible to implement. Probably worth raising an issue with them if one does not exist.

Comment: But the Java class "Mono" IS annotated (by package-info.java). This is why I'm confused why it doesn't work.